# Python: queue without blocking

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

I have a question about queues. I am creating a GUI with wxpython, and in the program I need to do something in a separate thread. After the thread finished, I have to modify the gui. The GUI should not block while the other thread is running.
For this I thougt about queues and wrote something like this:

```
def do_something(gui):
    # Here it normally does something
    gui.queue.put(gui.new)

class GuiFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title="Test")
        self.queue = Queue.Queue()
        self.calculate()

    def calculate(self):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=do_something, args=(self,))
        thread.start()
        function = self.queue.get()
        function()

    def new():
        # Here something modifies the gui
        pass
```

But the problem is now, that the program still blocks, I think because the queue is waiting for an item. I could start it in a new thread, but then I have to do the thing with the queue again, to execute the function in my main thread.
Can anybody help me?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use [wx.CallAfter()](http://wiki.wxpython.org/CallAfter). You may find some useful examples [here](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Non-Blocking%20Gui). Also you can use [pubsub](http://wiki.wxpython.org/WxLibPubSub) module to send messages to your GUI. Then your GUI won't block due to other threads.

[Here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/) is a nice blog that I read when I had a similar issue like yours. 
You can also find some other questions on SO based that may assist you to understand this concept [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22711787/crashing-of-the-app-with-wx-callafter-in-a-while-infinite-loop-in-wxpython-pyt), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22145892/adding-panels-to-gui-using-threading-in-wxpython), & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352601/what-are-the-bad-effects-of-not-stopping-killing-all-the-spawned-threads-in-pyth)