# Thread for UI design with wxPython

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

I'm currently designing a software UI based.

I have created a first python script used as my main source code.

Below is my script

```
import OneTouchToolLogs
import UserInterface
import wx
import XML_Parse
import threading


if __name__ == '__main__':

    #Init the logging - Tools and also logcat scenario
    Logs = OneTouchToolLogs.Logging()
    LogFileName = Logs.LogFileOpen()
    Logs.LogMessage(LogFileName, "LOG" , "Starting OneTouchAutomationTools")

    #Initialized User Interface
    Logs.LogMessage(LogFileName, "LOG" , "Loading user interface")
    app = wx.App()
    frame = UserInterface.UserInterface(None, -1, 'OneTouchAutomation')
    app.MainLoop()
```

I have created another python file which contain the class UserInterface to make it clearer.

The new python class is done as below:

```
import wx


class UserInterface(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent,id, title)        
        self.parent = parent
        self.worker = None
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        menubar =wx.MenuBar()
        #CREATE FILE MENU SECTION
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_NEW, '&New suites\tCTRL+N')
        fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, '&Open suites\tCTRL+O')
```

With the design, I have done, the UI become a blocking point for the overall execution as it's not done on a thread.

I have modified my main script to replace

```
   app.MainLoop()
```

by

```
   t = threading.Thread(target=app.MainLoop)
   t.setDaemon(1)
   t.start()
```

The result is that the thread is well created but he is killed in a second. I just see the window and it's close.

Any one know I to be able to create this interface using my UserInterface class and start it in a thread to allow the main program to continu ?

Comment: all your gui needs to be handled in your main thread... the wx documentation mentions this in several places afaik

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23425882/2382792

Comment: I think I should change the way I design it. I think my user interface will be my main python script.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, you will want the wxPython script to be the main application (i.e. the main thread). If you have a long running task, such as parsing a file, downloading a file, etc, then you will put that into a separate thread that your wxPython program will create. To communicate from the spawned thread back to the wxPython program, you will need to use a thread-safe method, such as wx.CallAfter or wx.PostEvent.

I recommend checking out the wxPython wiki for additional information:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks

Comment: Thanks. I will keep this in mind.I have been able to make it work. At this time, the UI is working and also menu. I have created a settings menu with a dialog box to enter some values inside. I'm currently facing a freeze of the main app. I'm opening the main application, click on settings. the dialog box appears and when I click to Cancel, I use self.destroy() to kill the dialog box. The dialog box is killed but the main application become unusable. I can access to menu but all items listes are greyed

Comment: I am guessing **self** is referring to the frame or the panel and not the dialog. You need to make sure you are destroying the dialog reference, not a reference to something in the frame.