# In wxPython what should the MainThread do while a separate thread is doing some work?

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

I have an OnClick function that is bound to a wx.Button object and when I click it, the function is run, it creates a thread and starts doing work behind the scenes. What should I do after this on the MainThread while the other thread finishes, to make the UI remain responsive? I'm currently doing this (in the main thread):

```
worker_thread = Thread(target = self.DoWork, name = "Solo Worker Thread")
worker_thread.start()

while worker_thread.is_alive():      
    self.Update() #self being the class that inherits wx.Panel
```

However the GUI is still unresponsive. Am I calling the wrong method?

Comment: Just return from the onclick function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example

```
while worker_thread.is_alive():      
    # do something
```

will block your GUI and eat up all available CPU cycles to ask the `worker_tread` if it is still working. wxPython seems to be not updateable if you block the main thread, even not if you force the update with `wx.Yield` or `….Update()`.

Therefore delete your `while …` statement. You can do the following to determine if the spun-off thread is still alive:

- Signal the conclusion of the thread by calling back to the main-thread with the thread-save `wx.CallAfter` added to the end of the worker
- Install a `wx.Timer` (e.g. every 1000 milliseconds) which polls the `worker_thread` if it is still alive

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [wx.CallAfter()](http://wiki.wxpython.org/CallAfter). You may find some useful examples [here](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Non-Blocking%20Gui). Also you can use [pubsub](http://wiki.wxpython.org/WxLibPubSub) module to send messages to your GUI. Then your GUI won't block due to other threads.

[Here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/) is a nice blog that I read when I had a similar issue like yours. 
You can also find some other questions on SO based that may assist you to understand this concept [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22711787/crashing-of-the-app-with-wx-callafter-in-a-while-infinite-loop-in-wxpython-pyt), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22145892/adding-panels-to-gui-using-threading-in-wxpython), & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352601/what-are-the-bad-effects-of-not-stopping-killing-all-the-spawned-threads-in-pyth)

Comment: no need for wx.CallAFter, I refactored my code, so no wx calls are made from non-main threads, but what should my function called from the main thread do while waiting for the separate thread to finish? I want to keep the GUI responsive.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything. As long as the long running process is happening in a different thread, it shouldn't be blocking the GUI's main loop. See the following resources for examples:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/

If you take a look at those, you will see that you spin up a thread and the thread does not block the UI.